# Handle Back Button Key during Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Actually the Problem is i just load a Fragment(**let call be Fragment-A**) From the Navigation Drawer now the Fragment-A call a Dummy Activity, and the Dummy Activity Load a **Fragment-B** than fragment-B call a **Fragment C** and the fragment-C call the **Fragment-D**..

**Overall Above picture:**

Fragment-A(call)-->Dummy Activity(load)-->fragment-B(call)-->fragment-C(call)-->fragment-D(call)

Now i have Some Question Regarding this:

- Actually there is one button in Fragment D, when the button is invoke i have to go back to the **Fragment-A**
- now During the fragment(B,C& D) load i have to handle the `On Back` Pressed..
  means if user in fragment D than on back press, than Fragment-C is load and vice versa but when the user is on Fragemnt-B an invoke the `On-back` key than Fragment A is load

**NOTE :**

- i have to handle Both Above Back key or System Back Key
- I know i have to maintain the Fragment Stack but how can i pass the case one

  [image]

[image]

### Edit:

- Actually the Fragment-A is the Part of Activity-(a) and the remaing Fragmnets(B,C&D) is the Part of Activity-(X)

### Code:

Repo link : [Code link](https://github.com/Dhruvdt/FragmentManager)

Answer (score 0):

The above scenario can be solved by below..

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

If the button in the fragment D invoked, please call the function 
getActivity().onBackPresses();
It will finish the current Activity..

Comment: Please post your code in github and share the link @DhruvTyagi

Comment: @DhruvTyagi Please check this reps https://github.com/rajajawahar/Dhruv-FragmentMananger

Comment: i check it but issue is still there when 2nd Activity->>2nd fragment is load and we press back key, so ideally it goes to the 2nd Activity, First Fragment  but it goes to the 1Activity 2nd Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the fragments in backstack as follows:-

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentA);
//No need to put fragment A in backstack


ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentB);
ft.addToBackStack(null);


ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentC);
ft.addToBackStack(null);

ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentD);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Now, All your fragments are in backstack so if you press Back on fragmentD then fragmentC will be shown and on pressing Back in fragmentC, fragmentB will be shown and on pressing Back in fragmentB, fragmentA will be shown.

AS, you mentioned you have a special button in fragmentD which on pressing should take you on fragment A, So on clicking that button execute this code:-

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {    
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: now i understand your point... bt there is little bit update in my question(So please check it sir)... anyway it's working... but i have little bit issue i have to manage the Fragment Menu Back Button